# Select doesn't have options property in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have problems looping a TypeScript array. These are the methods:

```
getNotification(evt: string, rowIndex: number) {
    console.log("Production order: law has changed to " + evt + " " + rowIndex);
    var select = document.getElementsByName("ProductId-" + rowIndex);

    this.removeOptions(select);

    if ((evt != null) && (evt != "")) {
        let productsByLaw: IProduct[];

        productsByLaw = this.products.filter(x => x.lawId == +evt);
        for (let product in productsByLaw) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(product.name, product.productid);
        }
    }

}

removeOptions(selectbox : any) {
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if `var select = document.getElementsByName("ProductId-" + rowIndex);` is the right way to get a html `select` because when I do `select.options[select.options.length]` I get this compiler time error:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'options' does not exist on type
>   'NodeListOf'.

How can I get a `select` with TypeScript?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("ProductId-" + rowIndex)[0]` - you need to get the `[0]` element

Comment: @KobyDouek But I still get the same error: it doesn't recognize `options` property.

Comment: Have you tried casting? `var select  = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByName(...)[0])`

Comment: select.options is array and your accessing (select.options.length)th element insted use select.options[select.options.length-1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I make it work: using [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).

```
getNotification(evt: string, rowIndex: number) {
    let id: string = "ProductId-" + rowIndex;

    let select: HTMLSelectElement = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById(id);

    this.removeOptions(select);

    if ((evt != null) && (evt != "")) {
        let productsByLaw: IProduct[];

        productsByLaw = this.products.filter(x => x.lawId == +evt);
        for (let product of productsByLaw) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(product.name, product.productId.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes in the relevant lines.

```
//line 3
var select = (document.getElementsByName("ProductId-" + rowIndex)[0]);

removeOptions(selectbox : any) {
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}')[0];
```